# What does DMA-BUF is greater than the monitoring threshold mean?

Tags: android

I have one user that claims my app is crashing for them, the only crashlytics crash I have for that user has this stacktrace that doesn't tell me much.

```
Fatal Exception: android.app.RemoteServiceException: mypackage(12275) used 2688584kB DMA-BUF is greater than the monitoring threshold(1572864kB), occurring DMA-BUF OOM (with unwknown typeId:0)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.throwRemoteServiceException(ActivityThread.java:2050)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.-$$Nest$mthrowRemoteServiceException()
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2297)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
       at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:210)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:299)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8116)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:559)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
```

Out of millions of users, this has only happened to 8 users on the last 30 days in crashlytics.

Any idea what it could be related to? Seems to happen mainly on TCT and Xiaomi phones.